# How to different open activities without using position

Tags: java, android

This is a recipe app with categories and sub categories. I want to know is there any other command to open different activities besides position command. Because I have a problem when searching it becames alphabetical order, when i click the item it give me different result because the position is changing. I dont know what is the problem of my code is it the search function or the position command to open different new activities.

**MainAdapter.class**

```
public class MainAdapter extends FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<MainModel,MainAdapter.myViewHolder> {

private Context context;

/**
 * Initialize a {@link RecyclerView.Adapter} that listens to a Firebase query. See
 * {@link FirebaseRecyclerOptions} for configuration options.
 *
 * @param options
 */
public MainAdapter(@NonNull FirebaseRecyclerOptions<MainModel> options) {
    super(options);
}

@Override
protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MainAdapter.myViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull MainModel model) {

    holder.categoryName.setText(model.getName());
    holder.categoryDesc.setText(model.getDescription());

    Glide.with(holder.categoryImage.getContext())
            .load(model.getImage())
            .placeholder(R.drawable.common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark)
            .error(R.drawable.common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark_normal)
            .into(holder.categoryImage);

    context = holder.itemView.getContext();

    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final Intent intent;
            switch (position){
                case 0:
                    intent =  new Intent(context, ChickenActivity.class);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    intent =  new Intent(context, PorkActivity.class);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    intent =  new Intent(context, BeefActivity.class);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    intent =  new Intent(context, SeafoodActivity.class);
                    break;
                default:
                    intent =  new Intent(context, VegetableActivity.class);
                    break;
            }
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }

    });
}

@NonNull

@Override
public myViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.main_item,parent,false);
    return new myViewHolder(view);
}

class myViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    ImageView categoryImage;
    TextView categoryName, categoryDesc;


    public myViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        categoryImage = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.categoryImage);
        categoryName = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.categoryName);
        categoryDesc = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.categoryDesc);


    }
}
```

}

**MainActivity.class**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

RecyclerView recyclerView;
MainAdapter mainAdapter;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recView);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    FirebaseRecyclerOptions<MainModel> options =
            new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<MainModel>()
                    .setQuery(FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("category"), MainModel.class)
                    .build();

    mainAdapter = new MainAdapter(options);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(mainAdapter);
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mainAdapter.startListening();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    mainAdapter.stopListening();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.search,menu);
    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.search);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView)item.getActionView();

    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            txtSearch(query);
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String query) {
            txtSearch(query);
            return false;
        }
    });

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

private void txtSearch(String str)
{
    FirebaseRecyclerOptions<MainModel> options =
            new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<MainModel>()
                    .setQuery(FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("category").orderByChild("name").startAt(str).endAt(str+"~"), MainModel.class)
                    .build();

    mainAdapter = new MainAdapter(options);
    mainAdapter.startListening();
    recyclerView.setAdapter(mainAdapter);
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of tying the Activity to a number you should tie it to a tag or some identifier. For example, you have 3 items in the list Like:

```
[
  {
    name: "chickenwings"
  },
  {
    name: "octopus"
  },
  {
    name: "tomato"
  }
]
```

Instead you can have additional information like the activity the item should correlate with, for example

```
[
  {
    name: "chickenwings",
    category: "chicken"
  },
  {
    name: "octopus",
    category: "seafood"
  },
  {
    name: "tomato",
    category: "vegetable"
  }
]
```

This will help you update your code like below

```
holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final Intent intent;
            val category = model.getCategory()
            switch (category){
                case "chicken":
                    intent =  new Intent(context, ChickenActivity.class);
                    break;
                case "pork":
                    intent =  new Intent(context, PorkActivity.class);
                    break;
                case "beef":
                    intent =  new Intent(context, BeefActivity.class);
                    break;
                case "seafood":
                    intent =  new Intent(context, SeafoodActivity.class);
                    break;
                case "vegetable":
                default:
                    intent =  new Intent(context, VegetableActivity.class);
                    break;
            }
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }

    });
```

Comment: OMG Thank you so much sir! This is exactly what I'm looking for. Great explanation. I just had 1 more problem in my search. I can just only search the exact name of my recipe. I cant search with a lower case letter first and no result is found if I didnt type the correct word in the search bar. Any suggestions? Thanks :)

Comment: You are welcome. You can accept the answer and upvote it since it helped you solve the problem. This will help others find the solution. Regarding the search, you can do an ignoreCase comparision instead of comparing the text directly, this will help you filter the text without case sensitivity. For example, `textToBeSearched.equals(comparingText, true)` this `true` is the parameter value for `ignoreCase` in the `equals` method.

Comment: I wish I could but I still can't upvote your post because I'm new here and I need 15 more reputations to cast a vote. But I'm so thankful bro. Thank you so much again!

Answer (score 0):

You can use "holder.getAdapterPosition"  instead of "position" to solve this problem.